# Combining Antlr 3.5.2 with StringTemplate 4 for code generation

Tags: antlr, antlr3, stringtemplate-4

Current project I'm working on is limited to using antlr 3.5.2, but I would like to use the featureset of StringTemplate 4 for our code generation. Can antlr 3.5.2 generate a java treewalker that uses StringTemplate 4? 
(e.g. a tree grammer with output=template that results in a java file with ST* references instead of StringTemplate*)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `output=template` option only supports StringTemplate 3. You can still support StringTemplate 4, but it would require using embedded actions or a hand-written walker similar to the ones ANTLR 4 generates automatically.

The ANTLR 4 tool itself uses the second option.